# OR operator in XDocument.Descendants LINQ query

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, linq, xmldocument

I have a collection of XML files with two possible root node values but with the same structure and child elements. I loop through each of the files and build an object `r` of type `Object` that I then add to a new `objects` collection:

```
foreach (var file in files)
{
    var r = from x in file.Descendants("RootNode")
        select new Object
        {
            Field = ((string) x.Element("Field"))
        };
    objects.AddRange(r);
}
```

I want to do something like:

```
var r = from x in file.Descendants("RootNode") || file.Descendants("OtherRootNote")
```

but can't figure out a logical way of doing this other than having two loops. Is that the only way?

Comment: I believe I can use `.Union()` but that still requires me to write two `select` blocks to create my `Object` which isn't ideal.

Comment: Yes indeed you can use `Union()` - Descendents returns `IEnumerable<Element>` so you can do standard LINQ on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Descendants()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360635%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to enumerate through all descendants, then add a standard [`where` clause](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311043.aspx) to filter those with the desired names:

```
            var r = from x in file.Descendants()
                    where x.Name == "RootNode" || x.Name == "OtherRootNode"
                    select new Object
                    {
                        Field = ((string)x.Element("Field"))
                    };
```

From the [reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Xml.Linq/System/Xml/Linq/XLinq.cs,bedbbeef7ca7eeb2), both [overloads](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xcontainer.descendants%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of `Descendants()` just do a linear walk through the element tree, so doing the name check yourself isn't computationally more complex.